# Grails Asynchronous Request with HttpSession behaves strangely

Tags: grails, asynchronous, httpsession

I have a simple controller with an action for a long running task and an action for checking a status of the long task:

```
class AsyncController {

    def index() { }

    def longTerm() {
        session.longTerm = 0
        session.longTermDone = false

        task {
            for (int i; i < 10; i++ ) {
                try {
                    sleep(3000) //NOT WORKING
                    println "  TASK: sessionID ${session.id} value ${session.longTerm++}"
                    //sleep(3000) //WORKING
                } catch (e) {
                    println(e.class.name)
                }
             }

             session.longTermDone = true
        }
        render(text: [] as JSON, status: 200)
    }

    def longTermStatus() {
        println "STATUS: sessionID ${session.id} value ${session.longTerm}"
        render(text: [successCount: session.longTerm, done: session.longTermDone] as JSON, status: 200)
    }
}
```

In the longTerm action there is a problem with HttpSession.

If the first line of code in the **task** closure is doing something with HttpSession the rest of the code is working fine. But if the first line is doing something else I get NullPointerException when I try to access session.id

Working code example is at https://github.com/machacekjan/StackOverflowAsyncRequest

Does anyone know why Grails behaves this way?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here appears to be that you're performing the `render()` outside of the `tasks` block. If you move `render()` inside the `tasks` block, the `NullPointerException` disappears.

I think this is because the `render()` finishes the request and you bypass the Servlet 3 Async support. You need to return a promise from the action, which `task()` does .

Unfortunately, `render()` doesn't seem to work with the async stuff in Grails 2.3.7 or 2.3.10. But that's a separate issue.